# Which way is correct and why?

Tags: javascript, json

If i wanted to assign a JSON value an Array from a method, which way would be correct and why?

```
obj:{ filters: myMethod }
```

OR

```
obj:{ filters: myMethod() }
```

given that filters expects an array of filters

```
function myMethod(){
    var filters = [];

    filters.push(new filter("filter1");
    filters.push(new filter("filter2");
    filters.push(new filter("filter3");
    return filters;
}
```

Comment: You cannot stringify a function, so you have to call the function using `()` I guess.

Comment: and you have ) missing in filters.push(new filter("filter1");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this one:

```
obj:{ filters: myMethod() }
```

it assigns result of function, another one:

```
obj:{ filters: myMethod }
```

just assigns function to obj, in other words you will have synonym to `myMethod`:

```
obj.filters()
```

btw, just pop up, is it string:

```
"obj:{ filters: myMethod() }"
```

? if yes, then you need to 'insert' result of myMethod(), otherwise when it is part of javascript code like

```
var a = { obj:{ filters: myMethod() } };
```

then it is ok. last one line can be stringified e.g. [using jquery](http://furrybrains.com/2009/01/15/json-parsing-and-stringifying-in-jquery-as-a-plugin/), if needed

Comment: Wouldn't the synonym be obj.filters()?

Comment: Good explaination of how the notation handles the data. However, keep in mind that functions are illegal in JSON.

Comment: @Kevin Peno: thank you. well, I do not deny that, and furthermore [json](http://www.json.org/) contains pairs 'string':value, so anyway JSON is written as _'obj':{ 'filters': [] }_ ...

Comment: Absolutely. Just wanted to make sure the op knew that what he's doing, if he followed this answer, was not technically legal. What should happen is a rethinking of how `filters` is used.

Answer (score 0):

Both are perfectly legal Javascript, the first will assign the function `myMethod` itself to `filters`, and the second will evaluate the function and assign its return value to `filters`.

In your case, since you're intent is to serialize this to JSON, you probably want to invoke the method (the second one).

Comment: legal in javascript, not legal in JSON

Answer (score 0):

The first will assign a reference to your method, while the second assigns the result of your method (the returned array).

To be more precise:
In first case obj.filters() will return the same as obj.filter in the second.

Note that obj.filters() will always call the method, while the second obj.filters is an array.

Answer (score 0):

It is illegal in JSON to supply function calls or anything else meant for execution (such as objects that contain methods). It can only contain scalar values, arrays, and lists. You would need to make the function call a name (similar to your first example, but as a string).

```
obj:{ filters: "myMethod" }
```

Then you would need to call the function using [`call` or `apply`](http://trephine.org/t/index.php?title=JavaScript_call_and_apply) or something similar.